# Length of entire regex pattern

Tags: regex, match, maxlength

I try to detect if a value is an int or float with a max length of 10 characters.

My best solution is `(^[0-9]{0,10}$|^([0-9]+\.[0-9]+){1,10}$)` but the max length of 10 characters doesn't work with a float number.

In this other solution `{^[0-9]{0,10}$|^[0-9\.]{0,10}$` max length works but the regex appear valid if the value start or end by "."

How I can control the length of entire pattern ?

Comment: What about using *two* conditions: First the regular expression to see if it's a valid number (not caring about length); Then a second to check the length and only the length or the input string.

Comment: I use this pattern with HTML5 attributs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an alternation here to cover both integers (no decimal point) and floats (has a decimal point):

```
^(?:\d{1,10}|(?![\d.]{11,})\d+\.\d+)$
```

### Demo

Here is a breakdown of the above regex:

```
^                   from the start of the input
    (?:\d{1,10}     match 1 to 10 digits, no decimal point
    |               OR
    (?![\d.]{11,})  assert that we DON'T see more than 10 digits/decimal point
    \d+\.\d+)       then match a floating point number (implicitly 10 chars max)
$                   end of the input
```

Comment: (You can omit the comma after 11) ++

Answer (score 1):

If your regex engine has positive lookaheads you can do

```
(?=^.{1,10}$)(^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$)
```

Comment: Be aware that `{,10}` quantifier doesn't work in many regex flavor, use `{0,10}` to be sure it will work everywhere. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PmH5H2/1)

Comment: With this solution the regex is valid if the value end with a "."

Comment: I think you should add anchors `^(?=.{0,10}$)[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?$` to prevent a partial match.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I have anchors in the lookahead

Comment: @Salamafet If you have a . in the number it has to be followed by one or more digits.

Comment: @JGNI That is correct and asserts 10 characters in total. But the match itself can match 1.1 inside the string `1.1.......` See https://regex101.com/r/wByBCz/1 If you also add an anchor to the end of the pattern, than that match would not be possible anymore. See https://regex101.com/r/ZFyxGy/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird ARGH!! yes. Will rewrite